# Broke XAMPP trying to downgrade. Need to eradicate and re-install

Tags: macos, xampp

When my laptop wiped a few months back, I had to re-install, and thinking I didn't have the original disk image anymore, I downloaded and installed what was then the latest version of XAMPP (1.7.2a).  I quickly became annoyed with some of the quirks of the new version's included version of phpMyAdmin, however, and so I frankly stopped bothering with it for a while.

Recently, I stumbled across the disk image for the original version I installed (0.7.4) again, and so I decided to attempt to downgrade it by following the instructions on their forums for uninstalling it in OS X ([link](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=32428&hilit=uninstall+OS+X)), after which I installed the older version.  It appeared to have installed just fine, but when I attempted to access phpMyAdmin, I ended up getting the following:

`Existing configuration file (./config.inc.php) is not readable.`

Removing, logging out, and re-installing again still produced the same error (in fact, the running commentary on the XAMPP control panel seems to indicate it may have screwed up XAMPP's Apache installation somehow, albeit pages still appear to load properly).

Shy of an archive and install, what options do I have to try and eradicate all traces of the old installations of XAMPP so it can start fresh with an installation of my desired version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the folder for the current installation, installed the desired version on top of it.  Re-installed Snow Leopard and it fixed the installation such that it's been running without issue since.